# Why does my foreign key in SQLite gets corrupted?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I'm struggling to understand why my foreign key in SQLite gets corrupted.

After reducing my code to the minimal working example, I'm stuck with

```py
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
bar = 99
create_foo = 'CREATE TABLE foo ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, bar INTEGER NOT NULL )'
create_baz = 'CREATE TABLE baz ( ' \
'    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,' \
'    foo_id INTEGER NOT NULL,' \
'    FOREIGN KEY(foo_id)' \
'        REFERENCES foo(id) )'
insert_foo = 'INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (?)'
insert_baz = 'INSERT INTO baz (foo_id) VALUES (?)'
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(create_foo)
c.execute(create_baz)
c.execute(insert_foo, (bar,))
conn.commit()
table = pd.read_sql_query(f'SELECT id FROM foo WHERE bar={bar}', conn)
bar_id = table.loc[0, 'id']
print(bar_id)
```

which returns `1`, and

```py
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(insert_baz, (bar_id,))
conn.commit()
table = pd.read_sql_query(f'SELECT * FROM baz WHERE foo_id={bar_id}', conn)
print(table.empty)
```

which returns `True`

If I look at the table

```py
pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM baz', conn).loc[0, 'foo_id']
```

I see that my foreign is now `b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`, while I was expecting `1`.

How does my foreign key get corrupted?

Comment: Be careful, using the name `id` is a bad idea!

Comment: Good point, and thank you for pointing it out :). I renamed the variable `id` to `bar_id` for the python code. Did you also mean that it's a bad idea to name the key column in sql for `id` as well?

Comment: I don't know if that might be a problem in SQL, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the types returned from `pandas` and my faith in automatic type casting was my problem.

The `bar_id` in

```py
bar_id = table.loc[0, 'id']
```

is of type `np.int64`.

Actively casting this to a normal `int`, i.e.

```py
bar_id = int(table.loc[0, 'id'])
```

solves my problem.